# Is there a way to structure docker images in different "enviroments"

Tags: docker

Im a developer, cyber security researcher, and and tinkerer....i have quite a few images pulled from various sources for various reasons. Is it possible to organize images into something like "categories"? For example, i have reconftw & nikto containers for pentesting, id like to have those in a different folder or environment than my development containers, simply for organizational purposes. Not sure if this is possible. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Would tags on the images do the trick? You can have more than one at the same time...
https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/image_tag/

Otherwise you could have labels on your containers
https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#set-metadata-on-container--l---label---label-file

Comment: Ideally, the same tag is deployed to multiple environments. https://12factor.net/codebase

Comment: I'm not OP. I don't really know what they want

Answer (score 0):

> id like to have those in a different folder or environment

Container images aren't stored in "environments" or "folders". The furthest "namespacing" you'll get is the Docker Registry where you pulled the images from.

All images are stored in the same location on disk for the Docker daemon.

---

You can setup "projects" using various `docker-compose` (or Kubernetes) spec files that use different images for different purposes, and **those** can be stored in folders.

```
pen-test/
  docker-compose.yml
tinker/
  docker-compose.yml
```